# Wrong value obtained using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

```
c=MyDB.rawQuery("SELECT Distance FROM " + Table1 + 
        " WHERE Source = '" + source + "'", null);

distance = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("Distance"));
```

The value of distance is 2.3 in the Database. However, when I display it's value on screen, the value of distance is being displayed as 0.

Comment: Missing the semicolon off the end of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done `c.moveToFirst();`? If you haven't no data will be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
c=MyDB.query(Table1,new String[]{Distance}, "Source = ?", new String[]{source},null,null, null);
if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

distance = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("Distance"));

}
```

Comment: The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[], String[], String[], null, null, null)

This is the error I get.

Comment: WHERE Source = '" + source + "'" << That line is wrong. It should be source = "'" + source + "'"  ....don't include the keyword where